# 3d array of range issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compilation

I have one table of range, basically, i want to find my score from it. My table looks like [image].

And my code looks like below:

```
let ageForRhr = [18...25,26...35,36...45,46...55,56...65,65...100]

    let menRhrScore = [ [49...55 , 56...61,62...65,66...69,70...73,74...81,82...200],
                    [49...54 , 55...61,62...65,66...70,71...74,75...81,82...200],
                    [50...56 , 57...62,63...66,67...70,71...75,76...82,83...200],
                    [50...57 , 58...63,64...67,68...71,72...76,77...83,84...200],
                    [51...56 , 57...61,62...67,68...71,72...75,76...81,82...200],
                    [50...55 , 56...61,62...65,66...69,70...73,74...79,80...200]]

    let womenRhrScore = [ [54...60 , 61...65,66...69,70...73,74...78,79...84,85...200],
                          [54...59 , 60...64,65...68,69...72,73...76,77...82,83...200],
                          [54...59 , 60...64,65...69,70...73,74...78,79...84,85...200],
                          [54...60 , 61...65,66...69,70...73,74...77,78...83,84...200],
                          [54...59 , 60...64,65...68,69...73,74...77,78...83,84...200],
                          [54...59 , 60...64,65...68,69...72,73...77,78...84,85...200]]
    func getRhrStatusFromScore (score : Int, age : Int , isMale : Bool) -> String
    {
        for index in ageForRhr.indices
        {
            if  let arr  = ageForRhr[index]
            {
                if arr.contains(age)
                {
                    if let arrVO2 = isMale ? menRhrScore[index] : womenRhrScore[index]
                    {
                        for indSub in arrVO2.indices
                        {
                            if let subArr = arrVO2[indSub]
                            {
                                if subArr.contains(score)
                                {
                                    if let activity = rhrStatus(rawValue: indSub)
                                    {
                                        return activity.getValue()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
    enum rhrStatus : Int
    {
    case poor           = 6
    case belowAve       = 5
    case average        = 4
    case aboveAve       = 3
    case good           = 2
    case excellent      = 1
    case athlete        = 0
   }
```

But unfortunately, swift compiler stuck while compiling above code. (Not giving any error or warning, just stuck on compiling swift files. If I comment above code it's compiling easily.) Please suggest a better approach for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift compiler has trouble compiling large array literals when you don't explicitly specify the types of the literals.  It overtaxes Swift's type inference system and it takes a long time or never finishes.

In this case, it seems necessary to give explicit types for the arrays themselves and the individual components.

These changes will allow your arrays to compile:

```
let ageForRhr: [CountableClosedRange<Int>] = [18...25,26...35,36...45,46...55,56...65,65...100]

let menRhrScore: [[CountableClosedRange<Int>]] = [ [49...55 , 56...61,62...65,66...69,70...73,74...81,82...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                [49...54 , 55...61,62...65,66...70,71...74,75...81,82...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                [50...56 , 57...62,63...66,67...70,71...75,76...82,83...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                [50...57 , 58...63,64...67,68...71,72...76,77...83,84...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                [51...56 , 57...61,62...67,68...71,72...75,76...81,82...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                [50...55 , 56...61,62...65,66...69,70...73,74...79,80...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>]]

let womenRhrScore: [[CountableClosedRange<Int>]] = [ [54...60 , 61...65,66...69,70...73,74...78,79...84,85...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                      [54...59 , 60...64,65...68,69...72,73...76,77...82,83...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                      [54...59 , 60...64,65...69,70...73,74...78,79...84,85...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                      [54...60 , 61...65,66...69,70...73,74...77,78...83,84...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                      [54...59 , 60...64,65...68,69...73,74...77,78...83,84...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>],
                      [54...59 , 60...64,65...68,69...72,73...77,78...84,85...200] as [CountableClosedRange<Int>]]
```

Your code has compile errors, and now that Swift is unstuck you can see and fix those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like a giant mess with so many different arrays. Define a proper data model like so:

```
struct HeartRateStatus {
    enum Gender {
        case male
        case female
    }

    enum Status: String {
        case athlete
        case excellent
        case good
        case aboveAverage
        case average
        case belowAverage
        case poor
        case unknown
    }

    var gender: Gender
    var status: Status
    var ageRange: ClosedRange<Int>
    var scoreRange: ClosedRange<Int>
}
```

And then the lookup array:

```
let rhrLookup = [
    HeartRateStatus(gender: .male, status: .athlete, ageRange: 18...25, scoreRange: 49...55),
    HeartRateStatus(gender: .male, status: .athlete, ageRange: 26...35, scoreRange: 49...54),
    // ...
    HeartRateStatus(gender: .female, status: .athlete, ageRange: 18...25, scoreRange: 54...60),
    HeartRateStatus(gender: .female, status: .athlete, ageRange: 26...35, scoreRange: 54...59),
    HeartRateStatus(gender: .female, status: .poor, ageRange: 65...Int.max, scoreRange: 84...Int.max)
]
```

Now your `getRhrStatus` function is clear and concise:

```
func getRhrStatus(score: Int, age: Int, gender: HeartRateStatus.Gender) -> HeartRateStatus.Status {
    let result = rhrLookup.first {
        $0.scoreRange.contains(score) && $0.ageRange.contains(age) && $0.gender == gender
    }

    return result?.status ?? .unknown
}
```

Test:

```
let status = getRhrStatus(score: 50, age: 20, gender: .male)
print(status)
```

Obviously this doesn't check for overlapping ranges, but it will return an `unknown` status if it cannot find the score.